# Provide validations while using UIPicker as UIDatePicker

Tags: validation, uipickerview, uidatepicker

#### **Hi,**

I am using a UIPickerView to accept payment card expiry date. As the date does not have date field, I could not use UIDatePicker. Now, I have got a nice picker which accepts months and year, which I stored in an array. So in the picker month section, It starts from Jan, Feb....Dec. But I don't like that. For example, the user should be able only to select Oct, Nov & Dec for the year 2011. The months Jan...Sep should be disabled. They should again get enabled for year 2012. How to do that ??

#### Thanks